# Change pure HTML Slider-Thumb color with jquery (working css included)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change the Slider-thumb color with jquery, but the problem is, that the same CSS-code, which I use in the StyleSheet is not working anymore if I use it with jquery.
The example below has a working css to change the thumb color, and a jquery button, which should do the same. Is there any solution, how this can be done with jquery?

Edit: The thumb is the thing which is moved. In this case the big round blue one. I want to change the thumb and not the track

HTML

```
<input class="topcoat-range-input" type="range" value="0" min="0" max="100" data-role="none" step="1">
<div class='button'>Change Color!</div>
```

CSS

```
.topcoat-range-input::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.36);
    border-radius: 30px;
    background: rgba(131, 208, 255, 0.75);
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 2px rgba(131, 208, 255, 0.75);
}
```

JavaScript

```
$('.button').on('click', function (e) {
    $('.topcoat-range-input::-webkit-slider-thumb').css('background', 'rgba(255, 208, 255, 0.75)');
});
```

Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/qcn6tmpz/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works fine if you remove the `::-webkit` part:

```
$('.button').on('click', function (e) {
    $('.topcoat-range-input').css('background', 'rgba(255, 208, 255, 0.75)');
});
```

EDIT:
Since you need the -webkit part, one (slightly messy) way of doing this, would be to add a style rule each time you click the button:

```
$('.button').on('click', function (e) {
    $("<style type='text/css'>.topcoat-range-input::-webkit-slider-thumb{background:rgba(255, 208, 255, 0.75)}</style>").appendTo($("head"));
});
```

Comment: Actually I want the thumb (the round one) in another color and not the track

Comment: So I need the webkit part

Comment: It works. but if You wants to change the color for every change in the slider You probably want to add title="test" to style and for evey click remove old color with jQuery('style[title="test"]').remove() just before adding the new one.

Comment: Well yes the edited version works, but I am just wondering why this is not working with the css() function

Answer (score 2):

Wrong jQuery selector

```
$('.button').on('click', function (e) {
    $('.topcoat-range-input').css('background', 'rgba(255, 208, 255, 0.75)');
});
```

In your case I would try to override css for this button .

```
.topcoat-range::-webkit-slider-thumb
```

Plain javascript seems to work:

```
for(var j = 0; j < document.styleSheets[1].rules.length; j++) {
    var rule = document.styleSheets[1].rules[j];
    if(rule.cssText.match("webkit-slider-thumb")) {
        rule.style.backgroundColor="rgba(255, 208, 255, 0.75)";
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually I want the thumb (the round one) in another color and not the track

Comment: The selector is not fine. I think jQuery can't select ::-webkit yet and this selector matches nothing.

Answer (score 0):

## Attach event correctly to the div with class .button

```
 $(document).on('click','.button', function (e) {

   $('.topcoat-range-input').css('background', 'rgba(255, 208, 255, 0.75)');
});
```

**

## http://jsfiddle.net/qcn6tmpz/4/

Comment: Actually I want the thumb (the round one) in another color and not the track. And my button listener is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is to define classes with the background color for the thumb. When the value changes, set the corresponding class name that maps to that value. For example, if the value if the slider is 2, we define a class name that provides the intended background color:

```
.slider2::-webkit-slider-thumb {    
background: gray;
```

}

The JS that handles the class mapping should look like this.

```
var styles = {"1":"slider1","2":"slider2","3":"slider3"};

slider.oninput = function() {      
  slider.className = 'slider ' + styles[this.value];
}
```

Take a look at this link for more details:

http://www.ozkary.com/2017/11/input-range-slider-with-color-indicator.html